Resize JTextArea with window
Hello i'm new to Java Swing and i decided to make text editor:
import java.awt.FlowLayout;  
import javax.swing.*;
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane scrollableTextArea = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollableTextArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollableTextArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        f.pack()
  
        f.getContentPane().add(scrollableTextArea);
    }
}

but JTextArea is not resizing with window
I tried getting window size and resizing JTextArea by window size (i lost the code)
Please help!

You need to look at how layout managers work. Remove f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout()); Call pack() after you lay out the components

I suggest taking another look into Layout Managers and how they work. The official tutorial is a good place to start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

Why did you even add the line f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());? It’s specifically asking for the behavior you don’t want. Besides that, there’s no reason to do f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); twice. And, as said, pack() should come after you added the components. And f.setVisible(true); should come even after that; it should be the last thing. And since pack() will size the window properly, the f.setSize(500, 500); statement is unnecessary.

Why are you using a ScrollPane if you want the text area to resize with the window?

@matt Why are you using a ScrollPane if you want the text area to resize with the window?  -if you have a hundred lines of text you still want to be able to see all the line of text (by scrolling) in case all the text can't fit in the space available to the window. A JTextArea, JTextPane are almost always added to a scroll pane for this reason.

When you create the JTextArea you should use code like new JTextArea(10, 40) to specify the default rows/columns for the text area so that when you "pack" the frame the text area can be displayed at a reasonable size.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the Laying Out Components Within a Container section.
Study the rest of the tutorial later.
Here's a GUI that illustrates a JTextArea that changes size when the JFrame changes size.  I used Swing layout managers.

All Swing applications must start with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the Event Dispatch Thread.
A JFrame has a default BorderLayout.  I used a BorderLayout for my JPanel.
Get into the habit of placing Swing components in a JPanel.
Use much more descriptive field names.  Use multiple methods and classes.  It makes the code easier for other people to read and understand.
Here's the complete runnable code.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JTextAreaExample2 implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JTextAreaExample2());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTextArea Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createTextAreaPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createTextAreaPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 60);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

}

